# How to add custom left-link models to wagtail admin page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I've been trying to add a left-link to the wagtail administration interface sidebar so that I can provide an easier experience to moderators. 
My ultimate goal is to add a collection of custom objects (already made), editable from the sidebar from wagtail's admin interface, and displaying that collection on the site's home page.

[Wagtail left links example (taken from official documentation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyJWx.png)

I'm new to python/Django and especially new in Wagtail, but I didn't find any help with this on official documentation. Is there an easy way to do this? Or you have to edit Wagtail source code? 
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wagtail's [modeladmin module](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) allows you to set up editing interfaces for arbitrary Django models, available through the admin menu. Alternatively, for lower-level control, you can add menu items through the [`register_admin_menu_item` hook](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#register-admin-menu-item).